# Using std::make_pair requires explicit types with boost::flat_map for some reason

Tags: c++, boost

This simple test seems to have problems with the MSVC2015 compiler but I'm not sure why

```
    #include <boost\container\flat_map.hpp>

TEST_METHOD(TestMap) {
    // Map declaration
    boost::container::flat_map<std::string, float> map2;
    // This works
    map2.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, float>("foo", 1.0F));
    // This errors
    map2.insert(std::make_pair("foo", 1.0F));
    // This (my preferred solution) also errors with same error as previous line
    map2.insert({"foo", 1.0F});
    // This works fine but is less efficient so I don't want to do this
    map2["foo"] = 1.0F;
}
```

Error is

```
unittest1.cpp(54): error C2668: 'boost::container::flat_map<std::string,float,std::less<Key>,boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<std::string,float>>>::insert': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key=std::string
1>          ]
1>  h:\users\mushfaque.cradle\documents\cpp\include\boost\container\flat_map.hpp(847): note: could be 'void boost::container::flat_map<std::string,float,std::less<Key>,boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<std::string,float>>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string,float>>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Key=std::string
1>          ]
1>  h:\users\mushfaque.cradle\documents\cpp\include\boost\container\flat_map.hpp(752): note: or       'std::pair<boost::container::container_detail::vec_iterator<Pointer,false>,bool> boost::container::flat_map<std::string,float,std::less<Key>,boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<std::string,float>>>::insert(boost::container::container_detail::pair<Key,T> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Pointer=std::pair<std::string,float> *,
1>              Key=std::string,
1>              T=float
1>          ]
1>  h:\users\mushfaque.cradle\documents\cpp\include\boost\container\flat_map.hpp(737): note: or       'std::pair<boost::container::container_detail::vec_iterator<Pointer,false>,bool> boost::container::flat_map<std::string,float,std::less<Key>,boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<std::string,float>>>::insert(std::pair<std::string,float> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Pointer=std::pair<std::string,float> *,
1>              Key=std::string
1>          ]
1>  h:\users\mushfaque.cradle\documents\cpp\include\boost\container\flat_map.hpp(722): note: or       'std::pair<boost::container::container_detail::vec_iterator<Pointer,false>,bool> boost::container::flat_map<std::string,float,std::less<Key>,boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<std::string,float>>>::insert(const std::pair<std::string,float> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Pointer=std::pair<std::string,float> *,
1>              Key=std::string
1>          ]
```

I don't understand why the type deduction doesn't work and I have to explicitly state it every time.

Comment: Side note: you should never pass explicit template arguments to `std::make_pair`, it's not designed for that (and since C++11, it will mess with its forwarding capabilities). If you find you need to specify the pair's template arguments explicitly, construct a `std::pair` directly.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to do Angew. How though (in this case)?

Comment: That would be `map2.insert(std::pair<std::string, float>("foo", 1.0F));`

Comment: doesn't that defeat the point of `make_pair`?

Comment: And I just tried it, gives error `C2668: 'boost::container::flat_map<std::string,float,std::less<_Kty>,boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<std::string,float>>>::insert': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>          ]`
 So I'm not sure of the correct `c++11` approach

Comment: The *sole* point of `make_pair` is "crate a pair with types deduced from initialiser." If that doesn't work for you, don't use `make_pair`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `make_pair("Foo", 1.0f)` returns a `std::pair<const char*, float>`, which is not a `std::pair<std::string, float>` but is convertible to one.

`flat_map`'s `insert`, meanwhile, has a non-standard extra overload taking a `movable_value_type&&`, where `movable_value_type` is a `boost::container::container_detail::pair<std::string, float>`, which, apparently, can also be constructed from a `std::pair<const char*, float>`.

All user-defined conversions are equally good, the compiler doesn't know which one to pick, so it complains.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought too, so I tried
`map2.insert(std::make_pair(static_cast<std::string>("foo"), 1.0F));` which works and `map2.insert({ static_cast<std::string>("foo"), 1.0F });` which doesn't. Neither of which I like; though again the 2nd one should evaluate to the same type?

I accepted your answer but it would be nice to get a concise way of making this work

Comment: `map.insert(std::string("foo"), 1f)` or `map.insert("foo"s, 1f)` should do, right @Ronnie

Comment: @Ronnie `map2.emplace("foo", 1.0F);`